# How can I use a button for calling a methods in Android Things

Tags: android, android-studio, android-things

I need to use a button for calling a method every time this button is pressed.
The type of button is GPIO

Answer (score 3):

From https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/gpio:

```
private val gpioCallback = object : GpioCallback {
        override fun onGpioEdge(gpio: Gpio): Boolean {
            // Read the active low pin state
            if (gpio.value) {
                // Pin is LOW
            } else {
                // Pin is HIGH
            }

            // Continue listening for more interrupts
            return true
        }

        override fun onGpioError(gpio: Gpio, error: Int) {
            Log.w(TAG, "$gpio: Error event $error")
        }
    }
```

Registering the callback:

```
class HomeActivity : Activity() {

        private var gpio: Gpio? = null
        ...

        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()

            // Begin listening for interrupt events
            gpio?.registerGpioCallback(gpioCallback)
        }

        override fun onStop() {
            super.onStop()
            // Interrupt events no longer necessary
            gpio?.unregisterGpioCallback(gpioCallback)
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />` permission in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the previous answer is perfectly correct. However, you can instead use the Button driver from the contrib-drivers that simplifies the creation and handling of the peripherals, and also adds debouncing.

You need to add the library to gradle dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    [...]
    implementation 'com.google.android.things.contrib:driver-button:+'
}
```

And then initialize it and register an `OnButtonEventListener`.

```
class ButtonDriverActivity : Activity() {

    private lateinit var button: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        button = Button(GPIO_BUTTON, Button.LogicState.PRESSED_WHEN_LOW)
        buttonA.setOnButtonEventListener { button: Button, state: Boolean ->
            // Your code here
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        button.close()
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />` permission in the manifest.